# Ping pong game: ball bounces like crazy

Tags: c#, xna

I am very new to C# and XNA and well.. just new to programming in general as well.

So, as an assignment, I need to make a ping pong game using xna.

I was doing alright until I realized that the ball bounces like crazy on the bottom of the screen for a reason that I cannot identify.

Below is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;


namespace PongGame
{
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    SpriteFont score;

    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Texture2D leftPaddle;
    Texture2D rightPaddle;
    Texture2D centerLine;

    private Texture2D ball;
    private Vector2 leftPaddlePosition = new Vector2();
    private Vector2 rightPaddlePosition = new Vector2();
    private Vector2 centerLinePosition = new Vector2();
    private Vector2 ballPosition = new Vector2();
    private Vector2 ballVelocity = new Vector2();
    private int WIDTH, HEIGHT;
    private int scoreOne=0;
    private int scoreTwo=0;
    private int round = 1;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        WIDTH = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
        HEIGHT = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
        leftPaddlePosition = new Vector2(0, (HEIGHT / 2)-40);
        rightPaddlePosition = new Vector2(WIDTH-30, (HEIGHT / 2)-40);
        centerLinePosition = new Vector2(WIDTH / 2, 0);
        ballPosition = new Vector2((WIDTH / 2)-15, (HEIGHT / 2)-15);

        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        leftPaddle = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
        leftPaddle.SetData(new[] { Color.White });
        rightPaddle = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
        rightPaddle.SetData(new[] { Color.White });
        centerLine = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
        centerLine.SetData(new[] { Color.White });

        score = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("score1");

        ball = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ball2");

    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();


        if (round % 2 != 0)
        //when the round is an odd numbered round,
        {
            ballVelocity = new Vector2(4f, 4f);
        }
        else if (round % 2 == 0)
        {
            ballVelocity = new Vector2(-4f, 4f);
        }


        KeyboardState key;

        key = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            leftPaddlePosition.Y -= 5f;

        }

        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            leftPaddlePosition.Y += 5f;
        }

        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            rightPaddlePosition.Y -= 5f;
        }

        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            rightPaddlePosition.Y += 5f;
        }

        //Left paddle manipulation
        if (leftPaddlePosition.Y < 0)
        {
            leftPaddlePosition.Y = 0;
        }
        if (leftPaddlePosition.Y > HEIGHT-80)
        {
            leftPaddlePosition.Y = HEIGHT-80;
        }

        //Right paddle manipulation
        if (rightPaddlePosition.Y < 0)
        {
            rightPaddlePosition.Y = 0;     
        }

        if (rightPaddlePosition.Y > HEIGHT - 80)
        {
            rightPaddlePosition.Y = HEIGHT - 80;
        }

        //Making sure that the ball stays within the window
        if (ballPosition.Y >= HEIGHT - 30)
        {
            ballVelocity.Y *= -1;
        }
        if (ballPosition.Y <= 0)
        {
            ballVelocity.Y *= -1;
        }

        //Checking if the ball goes over the left gutter
        if (ballPosition.X < 29.9f)
        {
            ballPosition.X = 29.9f;
            ballVelocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
            scoreTwo++; 
            round++;
            Initialize();
        }
        //Checking if the ball goes over the right gutter
        if (ballPosition.X > WIDTH - 29.9f-29.9f)
        {
            ballPosition.X = WIDTH - 29.9f-29.9f;
            ballVelocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
            scoreOne++;
            round++;
            Initialize();
        }

        ballPosition.X += ballVelocity.X;
        ballPosition.Y += ballVelocity.Y;
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(ball, ballPosition, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(leftPaddle, leftPaddlePosition, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(30f, 80f), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        spriteBatch.Draw(rightPaddle, rightPaddlePosition, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(30f, 80f), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        spriteBatch.Draw(centerLine, centerLinePosition, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(1f, HEIGHT), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

        spriteBatch.DrawString(score, System.Convert.ToString(scoreOne), new Vector2(WIDTH/4-10, 10f), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(score, System.Convert.ToString(scoreTwo), new Vector2((WIDTH/4)*3-10, 10f), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    } 
  }
}
```

I understand that it is quite a long code to post here but since I don't know where the problem lies, I thought it would be best asking you guys.

I also uploaded the game to a dropbox account.
[download link on dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49703432/pong.zip)

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually running the code I couldn't tell but SO is not here to write your code for you.

If it were me I would look at this bit here (seems like the most obvious suspect at a glance) ...

```
//Making sure that the ball stays within the window
if (ballPosition.Y >= HEIGHT - 30)
{
    ballVelocity.Y *= -1;
}
if (ballPosition.Y <= 0)
{
    ballVelocity.Y *= -1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I don't expect anyone to write my code for me but the thing is I tried playing around with the specific part of the code that you quoted and even made it do crazy things but it simply does not change the overall result hence I thought someone could give me a hint about the actual part of the code with the problem.

Comment: what is the behaviour you are seeing? is it just going up and down or is it moving left and right too? how far up the screen does it go?

Comment: also what happens if you comment that block out ?

Answer (score 0):

You should multiply the speed vectors by the amount of milliseconds sience the last frame divide by some speed constant (around 200).
This time is contained by the updatemethond's argument gameTime.